# Password fields being displayed as plain text in heroku logs for graphql requests (UnityWebRequest)

Tags: unity-game-engine, heroku, graphql, graphene-django, unitywebrequest

I have an application with the following tech stack

- web frontend app in React
- backend with Python/Django
- GraphQL API using graphene + [django-graphql-auth](https://github.com/PedroBern/django-graphql-auth) for authentication
- MySQL DB
- hosted on Heroku

In addition to this, the backend is also used by another 3rd party app that authenticates to it and sends data to track activity in a VR application.

I realized that in heroku logs, all the requests coming from the VR APP (made in Unity), are displaying the password field in plain text. This does not happen if I try to login through the web app.

[image]

Decoding the relevant part for more readability:

```
path="/graphql/?operationName=Login&query=mutation Login {
  tokenAuth(username: "ANNBAC", password: "4379") {
    success
    errors
    user {
      pk
    }
  }
}"
```

Given this scenario I believe the way the requests are being sent from Unity are the culprit. Problem is that I'm not Unity developer and would have no idea how to fix this there. I don't even have access to the code as it belongs to another team. And I think the unity devs there are also not so familiar with working with web requests in general so I don't know how to properly guide them on the web part. I could though ask for them to post whatever relevant code in here if people find necessary to help tracking the problem.

Comment: Can you show us how your React app sends the login mutation to GraphQL?

Comment: it would be a lot of code to put in here, so I'll try to have just the more relevant parts. Will post in a bit

Comment: @ceejayoz . I added now. Let me know if you got the relevant parts you'd hope.

Comment: I removed the react code and edited a lot of the question. Further investigation showed the problem to be related to requests coming from Unity and not the react app

Comment: I would make it their problem. "Your code is sending user credentials in the URL." Report it to your manager and whoever's in charge of security.